# Number of ways to roll a 6 sided dice - Generating Functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In a graded assignment the question asks:

Find a generating function for $ar$, the number of ways a roll of six distinct dice can show a sum of $r$ if:
The first three dice are odd and the second three even.

It's been marked but I'm quite certain the lecturer is incorrect.

My answer is : $$(x+x^3+x^5)^3 . (x^2+x^4+x^6)^3$$

Am I correct that my lecturer is incompetent? It is not the first time this guy has done this. I want to lay a formal complaint.

Comment: Is your question regarding the correctness of your solution, or the competency of your lecturer?

Comment: Generally, include the problem exactly as stated, not as you remember it. We can't tell aobut competence based on one mistake, if it is a mistake.

Comment: It is possible you were expected to simplify: $$x^9(1+x^2+x^4)^6$$ or $$x^9\frac{x^6-1}{x^2-1}$$.

Comment: I have actually found the exact question on other online sources, with solutions. The solutions all match my own and not that of the lecturer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have given the question exactly as stated. Your answer does not match that of the lecturer.

Comment: @shardulc My question is regarding the correctness of my solution

Comment: Well if your problem is that your lecturer gave you a different solution, why are you keeping that solution a secret?

Comment: @joriki $$(x+x^3/3!+x^5/5!)^3 . (x^2/2!+x^4/4!+x^6/6!)^3$$

Comment: That's not an ordinary generating function; its coefficients aren't integers. It looks like he was trying to use exponential generating functions, but it's not the right exponential generating function either, since that would mean e.g. $9!/2!^3$ ways of rolling a sum of $9$.